# How to display the highest value per column using data from a table?

Tags: php, html, mysql

[My table looks like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PinIc.png)
This is my code to display the average per category. But I want to find the highest value per column. Like in C1.1 I want find the highest average value in that column.

```
<div class="container" class="col-lg-5">
<table class="table table-striped table table-bordered" >
<tr><th>Campus</th>
<th>No. of Staff</th>
<th>C1.1</th>
<th>C1.2</th>
<th>C1.3</th>
<th>C1.4</th>
<th>C1.5</th>
<th>C1.6</th>
<th>C2.1</th>
<th>C2.2</th>
<th>C2.3</th>
<th>C3.1</th>
<th>C3.2</th>
<th>C3.3</th>
<th>C3.4</th>
```

```
    <tr>
    <td>MAIN 1 - CABEIHM</td>
    <td>
            <?php   
            $queryn ="SELECT COUNT(dept_code) FROM employment where                                     dept_code=3 and empg_code=1";
            $resultn = mysql_query($queryn) or die(mysql_error());
            while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($resultn)){
            echo "".$row1['COUNT(dept_code)'];
             echo "<br />";
             }
         ?>
    </td>
    <td><!--1.1-->
    <?php

    $query1 = ("SELECT  ROUND(AVG(Compv11),2) , dept_code ,  camp_code
                                FROM performance 
                                INNER JOIN employment 
                                ON employment.emp_code=performance.emp_id AND employment.dept_code=performance.dept_id
                                WHERE empg_code=1  AND dept_id=3
                                ");
                $result1 = mysql_query($query1) or die(mysql_error());
            [enter image description here][1]

                // Print out result
                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1))
                {
                echo "".$row['ROUND(AVG(Compv11),2)'];
                }

        ?>
```

Comment: What do you want to do with the 'highest value'?  Do you only want it identified?

Comment: You can use the [`MAX()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-maximum-column.html) function from MySQL for that.

Comment: @jhenderson2099 I want to display it to make a report on it.

Comment: @rickdenhaan How can I use MAX() if my values are from  queries?

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean. You can just add `MAX(Compv11)` to your `SELECT` in `$query1` and have it available to echo into a column, just like you now have your average. Or is that not what you want?

Comment: @rickdenhaan I want to find the highest average in compv11, but the average is just save on a query. Is it posibble to use max on a variable. Can you show me how you add max in my select query?

Comment: Oh, I get it. So of all values you have in the C1.1 column (which I assume are different queries per row, correct?), you want to know which value is highest. In that case you want to do it from PHP instead of MySQL. Let me write an example in an answer.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @rickdenhaan Yes sir, you get it right. Please show me your answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the row with the highest average value from the C1.1 column, your best option is to calculate this in PHP.

You are currently outputting the values directly as soon as you get them from the database. You'll need to store the average values in a variable, so you can get the highest value later:

```
$averages = array();

$query1 = ("SELECT  ROUND(AVG(Compv11),2) , dept_code ,  camp_code
            FROM performance 
            INNER JOIN employment 
            ON employment.emp_code=performance.emp_id AND employment.dept_code=performance.dept_id
            WHERE empg_code=1  AND dept_id=3
");

$result1 = mysql_query($query1) or die(mysql_error());

// Print out result
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1))
{
    $averages[1] = $row['ROUND(AVG(Compv11),2)'];
    echo "".$row['ROUND(AVG(Compv11),2)'];
}
```

Note that I'm adding the result to index `1` of `$averages`, because your variables are called `$query1` and `$result1` and I assume that for all your other rows you use incrementing variables (i.e. `$query2` and `$result2` for the second row, etc.). What follows is not very efficient, I'll give you an alternative afterwards.

Once you have all the average values in `$averages`, you can sort the array:

```
arsort($averages);
```

This will sort the array in reverse order (meaning the first entry will be the one with the highest value) while keeping the index to value association. Now we `reset()` the array to be safe, after which you can get the index using the `key()` function and the value itself using the `current()` function:

```
reset($averages);
$highest_index = key($averages);
$highest_value = current($averages);

$highest_query = "query" . $highest_index;
$highest_result = "result" . $highest_index;
```

Now you know that the highest value came from `$$highest_query` and its result is in `$$highest_result`, in case you want to do something with that information. You can, for example, use `mysql_data_seek($$highest_result, 0)` to reset it and then you can fetch its row again using `mysql_fetch_array($$highest_result)`.

Although you should really consider moving away from the old, unsupported, `mysql_*` functions and toward `mysqli` or `PDO` for your database communication.

Now for that alternative I mentioned:

Depending on what you want to do with the highest value (you say you want to output it and "make a report on it"), you probably also want to know which `empg_code` and `dept_id` you're filtering on in your query, or the `dept_code` or `camp_code` you're selecting along with the average value.

So let's fill our `$averages` array with more than just the average values:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1))
{
    $averages[] = array(
        'avg' => $row['ROUND(AVG(Compv11),2)'],
        'empg_code' => 1,
        'dept_id' => 3,
        'dept_code' => $row['dept_code'],
        'camp_code' => $row['camp_code']
    );
    echo "".$row['ROUND(AVG(Compv11),2)'];
}
```

Now we can use `usort` to sort the array using a custom function:

```
usort($averages, function($a, $b) {
    if ($a['avg'] == $b['avg']) {
        return 0;
    }

    // note: reverse check of the example, because we want to
    // sort in DESCENDING order
    // https://php.net/usort
    return ($a['avg'] > $b['avg']) ? -1 : 1;
});
```

Now the data for the entry with the highest value will be the first entry of the `$averages` array:

```
$highest = $averages[0];

echo $highest['avg'];       // highest average value
echo $highest['empg_code']; // 1
echo $highest['dept_id'];   // 3
echo $highest['dept_code']; // dept_code for the highest average value
echo $highest['camp_code']; // camp_code for the highest average value
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you. Can I use this approach to find the highest value from all the criteria (like Compv11 and Compv12 and so on.) in one department

Comment: I cant understand your usort function

Comment: This usort function compares the average values for every entry in the array. `$a` and `$b` are the two array entries being compared (both of which are arrays themselves). If both entries have the same average value, the order is irrelevant so it returns 0 (meaning don't change the order). If the average value for `$a` is greater than the average for `$b`, that means `$a` should come before `$b` in the array so it returns -1. Otherwise, it returns 1 to indicate that `$a` should come *after* `$b`. That way, you end up with an array sorted by the `'avg'` values in descending order.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But now I want to display the column heading where the highest average is placed. Example C1.1 has the highest average then it should be displayed.